# Revert my reverted local commits and reset to main

Tags: git

Okay, so i am kind of confuse here and not sure what to do. Here is current state of my remote branch

```
commit_1
commit_2
commit_3
...
commit_9
commit_prod_code
```

All the commits from 1-9 needs to be moved to a separate branch and my master should be reverted back to `commit_prod_code`. To do so i ran this command

```
git revert HEAD~9..HEAD
```

One thing that I didn't realize is that i didn't put `no-edit` flag. Hence, mistakenly ended up changing all "commit messages" of those commits. Which i don't want to.

Now my local branch is 9 commits behind and is messed up with commit messages. I Want to reset my branch to master and do the "revert" procedure again.

How should i do it.

**UPDATE**

Here is my current state

```
$ git log --oneline                                                                                                                        [2h43m] ✭
36557cb revert_commit
7f2c406 revert_commit
9db362e revert_commit
202446d revert_commit
7cb109d revert_commit
ce3ebf7 revert_commit
ad75615 revert_commit
e234267 revert_commit
9285d48 revert_commit
753e421 revert_commit
67aa988 revert_commit
c5c7101 revert_commit
6386a3b revert_commit
28aee0d revert_commit
69c74b6 revert_commit
0e172ec revert_commit
5e1b1cb revert_commit
9b21c68 revert_commit
commit_prod_code
```

What i want to do is to discard whole this revert process and go back to my original master state. This reverted code hasn't been pushed to anywhere

I tried doing `git reset --hard` and `git reset --hard HEAD^` but at the end it still shows me that my branch is 9 commits ahead of it.

All i want to do is cancel all this rever process, don't push these revert changes to upstream and reset my branch to remote head

Comment: What commits does the remote branch currently have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a hard reset to get back to a particular commit:

```
git reset --hard commit_prod_code
```

Or, you can hard reset to a branch on your origin:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Note that you'll "lose" all of your commits, but it sounds like that's what you want to do.

Avoid `git revert`. That just creates new commits that reverse prior commits, which can really mess stuff up when you attempt to merge back to your master branch. You should only use `revert` if a commit made it into a shared branch. I used `revert` once and it had the effect of nullifying someone else's changes, because it looked like I specifically wanted to remove some lines, rather than just "not add them".

---

Based on your update, it looks like you've basically rewritten your branch history. What you need to do is get back to your original commits which no longer exist in your branch. Not to fear... they aren't gone!

First, run `git reflog` to see a complete history of all the commits you've checked out. Scroll through the history until you find the commit you want to start over with, then run `get reset --hard <commit-hash>`.

Now you've rolled back your nasty revert commits.

Next, run `git checkout -b <new-branch-name>`. This will create a new branch with the current commit as its head, allowing you to preserve your newly recovered commits.

Finally, go back to your master branch and run `git reset --hard origin/master` to get your master branch back in perfect sync with your server.

**If your server is messed up,** then you'll need to run `git reset --hard <commit-hash-you-want>` followed by *[(danger, danger, danger)](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/)* `git push --force` *[(danger, danger, danger)](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/)*. If you've got anyone else working on this repo with you, then you'll need to warn all of them that you're about to change the master branch history. This will probably require some cleanup for any branches created after you messed up the server.

Comment: I don't want to lose all these changes. The **current** state of the code will be parked into a separate branch. The question is that how can i reset my current branch to master (I want to get rid of this rever thing for a while). I tried doing `git reset --hard` but it still shows my branch is **9 commits behind**

Comment: A revert will simply add a new commit, so you should be able to reset to the commit before your revert.

Comment: Perhaps j am not clear in my question. How can I discard my current revert process which hasn't been committed. I want to restart from the master but git reset --hard didn't help

Comment: Assuming you've not resolved the issue yet, can you run `git log --oneline` and update your question with the results?

Comment: updated with more details. All i want to do is cancel the revert process, don't want to push changes and reset my branch to HEAD of master

Comment: Updated my answer in response.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new branch from the ninth commit:

```
git branch newBranch <SHA-1 of 9th commit>
```

Now `newBranch` should have the 9 commits sitting on top of the `commit_prod_code` commit.  If you intend to have these 9 commits on top of another base, we could try cherry-picking or using rebase onto.

You may be done at this point, because you already made a merge commit in the original branch which undoes commits 1-9.